# Link items to a corresponding sub-site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have a list of items, and each item has a corresponding sub-site. I'm using a workflow to automatically create these sub-sites when an item is created.

What I want is to have a link to that generated sub-site instead of a link to edit the item. Is there a way to redirect it from editForm to the subsite?

Comment: You can change the view, remove the column which contains link to edit form and add a column which contains link to subsite.

Comment: Is it possible to do it in a way that isn't a raw hyperlink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your List I would suggest below points to achieve your task

1. Create a new column of type Hyperlink
2. In your workflow you can add extra step to update current item and populate this column with URL and Description OR You can manual add links to this column. Your wish.
3. Edit the view of your list, remove the column which contains the link to edit form, and include (*check the checkbox*) the column which contains link to subsite.

As per your question related to raw hyperlink, Yes we can show the text instead of raw link. The column type `HyperLink` itself OOB contains 2 properties i.e.

1. URL: which contains link
2. Description: Meaningful text for a link